# How does one add a custom filter to the admin customer grid for a custom attribute in Mage2 CE?

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, filter, custom-attributes

I'm working on a module that helps sync our CRM database with Magento2 as needed. One of the fields that syncs over is the `ID` of the person in the CRM database. This ID is well known as a 'go-to' field in our company to know which person we are talking about. I need to add a filter to the Magento admin UI customer grid for this custom attribute which I have added programatically.  I've searched, and I have found no solutions.

I'm searching for a solution which I can add to our module programatically. This needs to work in a CI environment, when the module is added to the latest version of Magento, the filter needs to be automatically added to the options in admin. No manual admin configuration explanations please. I don't think that is possible even, but still...

As I ask this question, I'm going to begin reverse engineering how Magento Core creates the filters. Hopefully, by the time I gain some knowledge on how they are built, I'll be able to implement any solution provided with ease.

**EDIT:**
I've added the following code to my `/view/adminhtml/ui_componenet/customer_listing.xml` file in my module. The field appears, and so does the filter, but it is not populated with the value inside the customer object.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="constit_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Constit ID</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">5</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: Same issue here. Did you manage it in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your `<item name="config">` (between filter and label):

```
<item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

I had the same issue but for the Product Grid. I'm sure this won't be much different.

Also you misspelled `ui_component` in your post but I assume that's correct in your module.

If that doesn't work, maybe the grid isn't loading your attribute, like I had with another custom attribute `supplier` I made on Order. To retrieve and display the attribute on the Order Grid I had to add this code to my module's `etc/di.xml`:

```
    <!-- Column supplier in Order Grid-->
    <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="supplier" xsi:type="string">sales_order.supplier</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```

Comment: I've been pulled off the project for now because we have dropped Magento2 for the time being.  I don't feel right accepting the solution without testing it, however I upvoted, and thanks for the answer. It sounds valid.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Did it this way in the end:

http://undefined.gr/site/2017/05/22/magento-2-1-creating-a-new-customer-attribute-and-adding-it-to-the-customers-grid/

Been looking around for this but couldn’t find a complete solution on this so I am sharing my findings.

I wanted to add an external reference code to the customer entity, form and grid, so…

indexer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Indexer/etc/indexer.xsd">
    <indexer id="customer_grid" class="Magento\Framework\Indexer\Action\Entity" primary="customer">
        <fieldset name="customer" source="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection" provider="Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\AttributeProvider">
            <field name="customer_ref_code" xsi:type="filterable" dataType="varchar"/>
        </fieldset>
    </indexer>
</config>
```

customer_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="ref_code">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Ref Code</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">5</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

customer_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <fieldset name="customer">
            <field name="ref_code">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Ref Code</item>
                        <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">ref_code</item>
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer_form.customer_form_data_source.customer</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field> 
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

InstallData.php

```
...

private function addCustomerField($customerSetup, $label, $code, $position = 1000)
    {
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $code, [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => $label,
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => $position,
                'position' => $position,
                'system' => 0
            ]
        );

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $code)
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
                'used_in_forms' => [ "adminhtml_customer" ]
            ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }
```

One thing is that I noticed that for some reason, during my various attempts, the fields is_used_in_grid, is_visible_in_grid, is_filterable_in_grid and is_searchable_in_grid where not set correctly so I had to go in there and manually set the to “1”. Then the field was ready to go on the edit form and on the grid.

Had to run indexer:reindex customer_grid to get the grid filled properly (if you use the flat catalog model).

The only thing I haven’t figured out yet is how to set put the new attribute in a different tab/group (fieldset) and keep it’s data. Seems to be ignoring my attempts.

Comment: links expire over time, please add the gist of it or key components to your answer if possible.

Comment: Yeah George it'd be great if you had any examples of what that page used to show

Comment: Apologies the site was down. Updated. Will try to add code here too